# Large memory dump file

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, dump

Just ran CCleaner and a it came back with something I've never seen before when using it:  a 3+gb memory.dmp file.

What are the reasons for such a large dump file?  I haven't had any crashes or lock ups recently.  The install is only a few months old...

Answer (score 6):

You must have crashed at one point. The size is basically equal to your RAM plus 1MB.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/01/08/understanding-crash-dump-files.aspx

You can set it to save less information. For more information, see this document on configuring the dump size:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/254649